# MySQL query works on one server but not on another

Tags: mysql, query-performance, data-migration

I am migrating our MySQL Server(5.7.15) to a more powerful dedicated box(5.7.24, data/schema created by a mysqldump from the old server about two weeks ago) and am having to recreate all the server settings that are not preserved by a MySQL dump.  I have this query(not written by me):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT t1.job_status, 
               t1.customer_po, 
               t1.customer_name, 
               t1.order_value, 
               t1.code_division, 
               t1.assigned_sales_person, 
               t1.date_assigned, 
               t2.date_order, 
               IF(t1.job_status = 'PENDING', 
               Datediff(Curdate(), t1.date_assigned), 
               Datediff(t2.date_order, t1.date_assigned)) AS days, 
               force4.Code('DV', t1.code_division)        AS code_desc, 
               t2.order_id 
        FROM   customer_po_log AS t1 
               left join orders AS t2 
                      ON t2.po_id = t1.customer_po 
               left join order_item AS t3 
                      ON t3.order_id = t2.order_id 
                         AND t3.code_division = t1.code_division 
        GROUP  BY t1.customer_po) AS u1 
WHERE  u1.job_status = 'PENDING' 
       AND u1.code_division = 'L' 
ORDER  BY u1.days DESC
```

On the original server, the query completes in .5 seconds.  on the new server it overruns the maximum query time.  I'm pretty sure the problem stems from the t3 join because of what the "Explain Current Statement" tool is telling me:

[image]
[image]

Is there a setting that is blocking this query from performing the same on the new box?  What is the cause of the difference?

Happy to provide any additional necessary information. Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain the tables on the new server have the same indexes as on the old server? Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl` to check. Have you done `OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl;` for each table after migrating them?

Comment: create scripts/indexes are the same but holy moly the `optimize` did it.  can't believe it can make such a huge impact on a query.  Thanks! Feel free to make this an answer so i can accept

Comment: I think analyze table would do the trick as well as looks like optimizer did not have index statistic for choosing correct index. However, I see an issue with the query: inner sub-query results not stable. I mean they might be different because only obe column is used for grouping and as a result it might return anything in job_status per customer_po for example. It is up to SQL server to decide. One day optimizer might choose another plan (based on different index statistic) and this would change output (not only execution time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you migrate tables from one server to another, always check a couple of things:

1. Are you certain the tables on the new server have the same indexes as on the old server? Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl;` to check.
2. Have you done `OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl;` for each table after migrating them?  You can also do this from the command line with `mysqlcheck -o --all-databases`

Optimizing, or analyzing, a table regenerates some internal statistics. Those statistics help MySQL's query planner choose indexes when they help with a query, so avoiding full table or index scans sometimes.

Comment: Possibly `--analyze` would have done the trick, but a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

(It would help to have `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`)

If you don't have these indexes, they might help with speed (on both machines):

```
t2:  (po_id, order_id, date_order)  -- with `po_id` first
t3:  (order_id, code_division)  -- in either order
```

Furthermore, the join to `t3` seems to be totally useless.  Since the Optimizer may not be smart enough to remove it for you, you should do that.

And move the `WHERE` inside

And get rid of the outer `SELECT`.

Ah heck, here:

```
SELECT  t1.job_status, t1.customer_po, t1.customer_name, t1.order_value,
        t1.code_division, t1.assigned_sales_person, t1.date_assigned,
        t2.date_order,
        Datediff(Curdate(), t1.date_assigned)) AS days,
        force4.Code('DV', t1.code_division) AS code_desc,
        t2.order_id
    FROM  customer_po_log AS t1
    LEFT JOIN  orders AS t2  ON t2.po_id = t1.customer_po
    WHERE  u1.job_status = 'PENDING'
      AND  u1.code_division = 'L'
    ORDER BY  u1.days DESC
```

plus

```
t1:  INDEX(job_status, code_division)  -- in either order
t2:  INDEX(po_id, order_id, date_order)  -- with `po_id` first
```

OK, you did not write the code.  But you now have the responsibility of cleaning it up.  Else the next developer will point the finger at *you*.

Comment: about 50 times faster :).  Thanks!